# Does iPhone have a Wi-Fi & Bluetooth toggle widget in Notification Center?

Tags: iphone, wifi, bluetooth, ios, notifications

I've just recently bought an iPhone with iOS8 last month. I noticed that although iphone has a control center when locked, it doesn't have any way to toggle Wi-Fi and Bluetooth from the notification center, that's available via apps/default in android phones.

Is there any free app with a widget in iOS8 that can let me toggle these settings via notification center? I searched online, but couldn't find any app.

I don't intend to jailbreak my iphone, although I found some web-blogs suggesting to jailbreak and use Cydia...

Comment: why it has to be from Notification center ?

Comment: I need to toggle wifi or Bluetooth easily without locking or sliding for the default toggle under lock screen's control panel or the settings. Required for access while using an app or just browsing net

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can toggle directly by swiping up from the very bottom of the screen…

...from the lock screen, home screen or in most apps [in some apps it's difficult to get the swipe to be recognised if the app uses the same part of the screen for a function.]

[image]

Comment: That doesn't help. For that I'll have to lock the iPhone, bring up the control center, toggle, and then unlock the iPhone again. Although it's not difficult, but it could be easier and faster to just slide down the notification center and toggle wifi via a widget. I haven't been able to find any widget for this.

Comment: Why would you have to lock the phone? Control Center is available by swiping up, on both the Lock screen and the Home screen.

Comment: You don't have to lock the phone. Control Center is available on the lock screen, home screen, and from inside any app.

Comment: @samh: I didn't know that. Thanks Tetsujin & Samh!

Comment: I clarified my answer.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible for a store-approved app to add a Notification Center widget as there are no public APIs for controlling Wi-Fi and Bluetooth power.

There might be private ones you could access with an app signed for enterprise or developer use, but using control center is a better idea for this.

Answer (score 1):

I found this question by searching "iPhone Notification Center Wi-Fi" on Google. In case anyone is looking, I ended up finding an app called Wi-Fi Widget (https://getwifiwidget.com). It doesn't let you turn off the wi-fi from Notification Center, but it does let you jump directly into Wi-Fi settings, where you can do that. It also has some other nifty features like showing connection status.

I am not affiliated with this app.